# Cant see MacBook in Windows Network

Tags: mac, windows, network, file-sharing

I'm trying to access my MacBook from a Windows PC over the network. The computer is connected to the router, the MacBook is connected to a WAP, which is connected to a switch, which is connected to the router.

When I click on Network on the PC, the MacBook doesn't show up. It has done previously. Sometimes the Windows computer shows in the Finder sidebar and sometimes it doesn't.

How can I make the MacBook show in Network [Places] on the Windows machine? And how do I make the Windows machine stay in the Finder sidebar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another issue is you might not be in the same workgroup. To fix this go to

System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> WINS:

Make sure his Windows box is set the same. What OrangeBox suggested must be done as well.

[image: workgroup setting]

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by taking the name given in the `NetBIOS Name` field above, open a run dialog with <kbd>![Windows Key][newwinlogo]</kbd>, and type \\ and then the NetBIOS Name (so in the above example the full path would be `\\MACBOOKPRO-D04A`)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve the issue by copying the name given in the `NetBIOS Name` field in the answer given by rubixibuc and pasting it into a run dialog, typing \\ and then the NetBIOS Name (so in rubixibuc's example the full path would be `\\MACBOOKPRO-D04A`)

To open the Run dialog, simply type <kbd>[image: Windows key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

[image: Run dialog]

Comment: This worked for me, but I also needed to enter a username and password. You can just use the same username and password that you use to log in to your Mac, but you need to type the username as `MACBOOKPRO-D04A\Username` where MACBOOKPRO-D04A is your Mac's NetBIOS Name.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience there is no quickfix way to get windows and mac machines to *always* be visible in the others networks list.

The best thing you can do is enable Samba filesharing on your mac, then when you want to connect you just type `smb://Jonathan's MacBook Pro` into the address bar in Explorer (or into the run dialogue).

**To Enable SMB sharing on your Mac:**

1. Go to **System Preferences > Sharing > File Sharing**
2. Select **Options**
3. Tick **Share files and folders using SMB (Windows)**

This has always worked for me with networking windows machines in Mac environments.

Comment: `smb:\\` results in a pop-up telling me that I'll "need a new app to open smb" but Windows can't seem to figure out what it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the workgroup name from the iMac and windows PC. I have same problem and after I change the workgroup name it work. Try to ping your iMac check if the connectivity is good. Start - run - cmd - ping and the IP address of your Mac.